# Salesforce Instance region and global user performance

Tags: instance

I'm currently working on building a CRM using Sales Cloud for a global business. I just wondered if there is any correlation between Salesforce instance's region (e.g. USA268S, AP10 etc,.) and performances like data loading.

For example, my salesforce instance is being serviced on AP10. And we have users of global sales reps from NA, FR, UK, JP, India. What could be the difference between Japanese and British users when they use Salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users accessing Salesforce from regions geographically closer to the instance's data center(example - Japanese users accessing AP10) generally experience lower latency and faster response times compared to users from farther regions (example - British users).

My recommendation would be to focus on having an org on instance where majority of the users (customers) access from. For example, if you think you have a large user base in North America, it makes sense to migrate or have your org created on a NA instance.

Comment: Thanks... I might have to find the best location..